# 1 Peter 2:7-8 different meaning on other language

Tags: predestination, 1-peter

> 1 Peter 2:
>  (7) Now to you who believe, this stone is precious. But
>   to those who do not believe, "The stone the builders rejected has
>   become the cornerstone,"
>  (8)and, "A stone that causes people to
>   stumble and a rock that makes them fall." They stumble because they
>   disobey the message--**which is also what they were destined for**.

Reading the English verse, it leads me to think that it's about Double Predestination.

Where verse 7 becomes like this :
*Because I predestined you to be in Heaven

Then you believe

Because you believe

Then the stone is precious to you.*

And verse 8 becomes like this :
*Because I predestined them to be in hell

Then they don't believe

Because they don't believe

Then the stone becomes a stumbling block to them*

But when I read the verse from the Bible on my own language, the verse's sentences have the sense something like this :

*If someone obey My Words

Then he/she will believe the stone

Then the stone is precious to him/her


If someone disobey My Words

Then he/she won't believe the stone

Then the stone is a stumbling block to him/her*

So, the sentence ***which is also what they were destined for*** in the Bible of my language is not like that in English one.

In my language, *"they were destined for"* in verse 8 has a sense that if the "IF" criteria by an external party (someone who disobey) is fulfilled, then the "THEN" follows ---> they are "destined" to stumble.

While in English language, it seems to me that it shows Double Predestination, starting from the *"Because I"*.

My question:
Is the Bible in my language gives a wrong translation ?

---

I just searched from the internet, and found a [link](https://www.monergism.com/thethreshold/articles/onsite/qna/double.html) which telling on what God says :

> Peter also speaks of those to whom Christ is the precious Cornerstone
>   of salvation and those who stumble against him to their eternal
>   destruction; and of those who are reprobate, he says clearly that
>   **they were “predestined” to disobey the word and so to perish** (1 Pet. 2:6-8).

So, it is the *"Because I"*.

Comment: In which language is your own bible written, may I ask ?

Comment: [Related question here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19455/does-1-peter-28-suggest-humanity-is-destined-or-called-to-purposes-set-by-god)

Comment: @NigelJ, it's in Indonesian language.

Comment: @Seeker, thank you for the link. I've read it, so the correct one : _"Because I"_. So, the Bible in my language gives a wrong translation.

Comment: The question is whether we are appointed to stumble or to disobey. Your language rightly points out we are not appointed to disobey, but if we disobey, the planned penalty is to stumble, to be blocked from fulfillment. The ESV translation is well known to favour Calvinist interpretations.

Comment: Seems like you got your answer but to use another language I found interesting and accurate. Because they did not believe the word, they hit themselves against the rock and as a consequence this is what is supposed to happen (to them). you hit yourself against the rock because you don’t believe the Word, this is expected.